# Sum of multinomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, multinomial-coefficients

I want to show that $$\sum_{j,k,j+k\leq n} 3^{-n}\frac{n!}{j!k!(n-k-j)!}=1.$$
I tried to do it by induction, but this clearly seems the wrong approach because the denominator becomes very hard to deal with. I also tried to form a binomial coefficient so that I can perhaps use a formula, but this is also too complicated since I have to deal with the cases where $k \leq j$ and vice versa. This fact was made to seem obvious in papers I read so I believe it can be proven some way.

Comment: Multiply both sides by $3^n$.  Your question becomes asking why the sum of multinomial coefficients is equal to $3^n$.  Count the number of ternary strings of length $n$ in two ways... counting directly by multiplication principle versus counting by breaking apart into cases based on the number of 0's,1's, and 2's used.

Comment: By the Multinomial Theorem, $$\sum \frac{n!}{i!j!k!} x^i y^j z^k = (x+y+z)^n$$ where the sum is over non-negative $i,j,k$ with $i+j+k=n$.  Now let $x=y=z=1$.

Comment: It's also easy to do by induction with the recurrence relation $\binom{n}{a; b; c} = \binom{n - 1}{a - 1; b; c} + \binom{n - 1}{a; b - 1; c} + \binom{n - 1}{a; b; c - 1}$.